# pointer attribute changes when reexamined

Tags: c++, c++11, object, pointers, vector

I am new to C++, currently working on a networking project, faced an unusual error with a vector of object pointers.

**State class:**

```
struct State
  {
    public:
      int reject_percent_;
      int fill_percent_;
      int partial_fill_;
      bool is_logged_in_;
      struct order
      {
        long id;
        long price;
        int quantity;
        bool is_filled = false;
        bool is_partially_filled = false;
      };
      std::vector<order *> orders;
  };
```

**pushing into vector:** (here state is an object of State struct)

```
State::order* o;

o->id = (obj->ClOrdID);   // obj->ClOrdID = 1
o->price = (obj->Price);  // obj->Price = 1
o->quantity = (obj->OrderQty); // obj->OrderQty = 1
std::cout<<o->id<<"\n";           //outputs 1
state->orders.push_back(o);
```

**in other function:**

```
State::order* ord = NULL;
    for (int i = 0; i < state->orders.size(); ++i) 
    {
      std::cout<<((state->orders).at(i)->id)<<"\n";  //outputs :: 93893845689152
      std::cout<<((state->orders).at(i)->price)<<"\n"; //outputs :: 93893845689184
      std::cout<<((state->orders).at(i)->quantity)<<"\n"; //outputs :: 869246848
      if(obj->ClOrdID==(state->orders).at(i)->id)
      {
        ord=(state->orders).at(i);
        break;
      }
    }
```

I know this is **not a minimal reproducible example**, but I think this might be a trivial error that I don't see, the code is big and will take a long time shortening, so please bear with me, can you just point out what might cause this problem, as the values seem to be junk values of the datatypes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You didn't allocate memory for the order and you didn't initialize the pointer

```
State::order* o;
```

Dereferencing this pointer to write into it

```
o->id = (obj->ClOrdID);   // obj->ClOrdID = 1
o->price = (obj->Price);  // obj->Price = 1
o->quantity = (obj->OrderQty); // obj->OrderQty = 1
```

to read from it

```
std::cout<<o->id<<"\n";           //outputs 1
```

or copying it

```
state->orders.push_back(o);
```

causes undefined behavior. Your program could crash, everything could seem correct or your computer could order a pizza.

It's difficult to say what's the best way to solve this problem with just some code snippets. One way is to change `std::vector<order *> orders;` to `std::vector<order> orders;`. Another way is to use smart pointers.

Comment: `and you are storing a pointer to unallocated memory state->orders.push_back(o); That causes undefined behavior` This is a bit misleading. `push_back(o)` is UB because the function reads the value and behaviour of reading indeterminate value is undefined. If the pointer was initialised with an actual invalid pointer value, then storing it into the vector would not be UB.

Comment: Cool, thanks for the informative answer, I am new to C++ and trying to do a hands on project to learn, I was sure it was something basic I was missing ;).

Answer (score 2):

> ```
> State::order* o;
>
> o->id = (obj->ClOrdID);
> ```

The pointer has an indeterminate value. The behaviour of indirecting through this uninitialised pointer is undefined.

You should probably use this instead:

```
std::vector<order> orders;
```

So that the vector contains order instances.

Comment: I would also recommend using a vector of unique pointers. Without knowing the complete, full code of the project, it's hard to judge whether a simple value is okay or if pointers really are needed

Comment: @GuillaumeRacicot I generally want to avoid introducing extra dynamic allocation into an example, unless the example demonstrates a need for dynamic allocation. I don't see a need for dynamic allocation demonstrated in the example code.

Comment: Cool, thanks for the informative answer, I am new to C++ and trying to do a hands on project to learn, I was sure it was something basic I was missing ;)